# How to remove WebAuthn credentials on Chrome MacOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webauthn, fido

For example, the one created on this WebAuthn demo page: https://webauthnworks.github.io/FIDO2WebAuthnSeries/WebAuthnIntro/UsernamelessExample.html

[image]

I found the similar question without answer on apple forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot currently remove them in the UI. A future release will bring this functionality.

Comment: It should be possible to manage the credentials using the CLI as showed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758767/how-to-delete-a-keychain-reference-from-command-line
On Windows, the issue is the same and I removed them using commands as an admin (for the record: https://superuser.com/questions/1527685/how-to-remove-webauthn-credentials-from-onboard-tpm-on-win10-device#:~:text=Try%3A%20(1)%20In%20Microsoft,also%20be%20worth%20a%20look.)

Comment: In addition and in case you missed it, it is possible to use fake credentials with Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/webauthn/

Answer (score 3):

Clearing browser data will remove them but, while it can be time-bounded, may also remove other data:

Three dots -> More Tools -> Clear Browsing Data... -> Advanced -> ensure that "Passwords and other sign-in data" is checked.

A UI for this is planned for Chrome 108